# Sum over binary tree of minimum size of children

Tags: combinatorics, computer-science, trees

True or false: let $T$ be a binary tree with $n$ vertices, then the sum of minimum child size can be upper bounded by
$$\sum_{v \in T} \min(\text{size}(\text{left}(v)),\, \text{size}(\text{right}(v))) \leq O(n \log n)$$

The right-hand side is achieved by the balanced binary tree.

Note that $\sum_{v \in T} \text{size}(v)$ can be $\Omega(n^2)$ if the tree is a path, but this edge case doesn't apply to the above.

Comment: What does $n$ mean?

Comment: Whoops, $n$ is the number of vertices in the tree.

Comment: Then what does "size" mean?

Comment: The number of vertices in the subtree at the vertex, or 0 if there is no such subtree.

Comment: Sorry, I was misreading the question.  I understand it now.